# spark.driver.memory relationship with "show()" and "count()", except() function performance in spark, scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently used the count() and show() functions using a large dataframe in spark.

And I got the error below.

```
Diagnostics: Container [pid=xxx,containerID=container_exxx] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 4.5 GB of 4.5 GB physical memory used; 7.1 GB of 9.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

I used spark with the specifications below.

```
spark.executor.instances   = 10
spark.executor.cores       = 2
spark.executor.memory      = 20g
spark.driver.memory        = 4g
```

Here is a simple sample example.

```
val df1 = Seq(1,2,3).toDF()
val df2 = Seq(2,3,4,5).toDF()
val df3 = Seq(3,4,5,6,7).toDF()
val df4 = Seq(2,3).toDF()
Seq(df1, df2, df3).foreach{ x =>
   val df = x.except(df4).cache()
   val count = df.count()
   println("count: count")
   df.show()
   df.unpersist()
}
```

I wonder if the driver keeps saving the calculation results for each df while the for statement is running, so I also used cache() and unpersist(), but nothing changed.

Even with such a simple code, the above error occurs, so I am in doubt.

First, The count() and show() functions are calculated in the executor, and the size sent to the driver is not expected to be large.

But, I don't know why that error occurred.

Second, I set the driver memory to 4g, but in the error above, I don't know why 4.5GB and 7.1 GB of 9.4 GB virtual memory used came out.

Finally, can I solve that problem without increasing the driver memory?

I want to know the root cause for the above problems.

Could anyone please explain the above three in detail?

Comment: `df.count().cache()` does not seem to work. Do you mean `df.cache().count()`?

Comment: 4.5 + 7.1 = 11.6, are you sure it is the driver memory that is relevant here? might it be exceeding the executor memory of 10g instead?

Comment: The code was modified.
It was a mistake.

Comment: Check the [yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ko/iis/11.5?topic=hadoop-configuring) and other vmem settings